# pull db row with foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Lets say I have 2 tables in my db

```
user:
id, username

userpost:
userid, post
```

I have defined a Relation to connect `userpost.userid` to `user.id` in side the db (mysql).

Is there a query (as simple as possible) to pull the whole row (including user's row)
WITHOUT knowing the relationship at the programmer side? meaning, relaing on the relationship defined in the db itself

something like `"SELECT * from userpost include foreign key"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT user.*, userpost.* 
  FROM user, userpost 
 WHERE user.id=userpost.userid
```

Possible problem would be the 1:many relationship between user and userpost: You would get each user-record multiple times (once for each userpost record)

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick reply. an edit has been done to the question.

Comment: No - that would not be possible (i know no database that has this functionality)

Comment: then why do they allow it to be defined if nothing can be done with it?

Comment: Foreign keys? Oh, there are actions being performed. Such as referential integrity checks or ON DELETE actions. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key